# Java char array copying yielding weird results

Tags: java, arrays, copy, char

I wanted to optimize my code, so instead of copying my entire char array for each iteration in the alphabet, I opted to do the copying beforehand and then I'd just add chars into the copy.

E.g.:

copy "lord" (i=0)

modify the first letter (aord, bord, cord &c)

copy "lord" (i=1)

modify the second letter (lard, lbrd, lcrd &c)

&c

```
    for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
        Word moddedWord = new Word(Arrays.copyOf(temp.word.content, wordLength));
        for (int c = 0; c < alphabetLength; c++) {
            if (alphabet[c] != temp.word.content[i]) {
                // Word moddedWord = new Word(Arrays.copyOf(temp.word.content, wordLength));
                moddedWord.content[i] = alphabet[c];
                Word res = WordList.Contains(moddedWord);
                if (res != null && WordList.MarkAsUsedIfUnused(res)) {
                    WordRec wr = new WordRec(res, temp);
                    q.Put(wr);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, when I do this small change, my program doesn't work, when it used to when I instead used the commented line for copying. I've debugged this for hours on end now and I can find *nothing* that changes this, I've tried various forms of copying, I've tried storing the "original" word as a String and then converting it to a char array when I need to copy it, nothing seems to work. Oh by the way, "Word" is just a wrapper for char[] (Word.content is a char[] field).

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Are you storing the same array over and over or do you get an exception, or what happens?

Comment: It starts infinite looping actually, which is *really* weird, since I've been using IntelliJ's debugger, which tells me it only gets to q.Put(wr) for valid words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't avoid copying if you want to store each modification of the word. Here:

```
new WordRec(res, temp);
```

you create a word record based on the *mutable* instance of the word and then you keep changing that one instance. You'd need to copy `temp` inside this constructor. So the best you achieve is copying a bit later, possibly a bit less due to the "ifology" within which it happens.

Now, if you really want to improve performance, then rework the `WordList` to be a `WordSet` and have O(1) lookup time with the `Contains` method.

A final note: please respect the Java naming conventions. Methods start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: I am using a HashSet for WordList currently, so Contains should already be O(1).  I've changed my Contains method for wordlist now to make a "deep copy" of the Word. Thanks!